# Issues with has_many in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to show all workers and all posts that belong to them, in the same view.

I'm fetching all workers with

```
<%= @workers.each do |worker| %>
```

and then posts with.

```
<%= worker.posts.each |post| %>
```

This works well, but I want to add a simple search function to the posts one

i.e

```
    <%= worker.posts.search(params[:search]).each |post| %>
```

but that gives me a undefined method error for search.

My understanding is that I can't add .search unless it's inside the controller, but I can't figure out how to define posts in the controller.

Things i've tried in controller:

```
@posts = worker.posts
@posts = @workers.posts
```

I've also tried to add:

```
@worker = Worker.find(params[:id])
```

To try and piggy back off, but that gives an error before I can try.

Some help would be greatly appreciated

Solution:

did it in round about way.

```
<% Post.search_post(params[:search_post]).where(worker_id: worker.id).each do |month, posts| %>
```

I'm sure there is a much better and cleaner solution, but this works for what I wanted anyway.

Answer (score 0):

worker.posts should return an ActiveRecord::Relation which does not have a method entitled search.

if you want to add one, you must do it in the model.

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :search, ->(options) {
    # logic goes here
  }
end
```

Comment: I have a search defined in my model, but it seems I can only call it from the controller. "def self.search(search)" and so on